# React Navigation 5 pass params when defining screens

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a Tab navigator that should rendend the same component but passing different parameter each time.

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export const AdminTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name='Pending'
        component={Tasks}
        params='pending'
      />
     <Tab.Screen
        name='Completed'
        component={Tasks}
        params='completed'
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

Is there a way to do this or should i create different component for each screen?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by passing  initialParams

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Main"
    component={MainScreen}
    initialParams={{ /* initialParams */ }}
/>
```